# Return a list of all ancestor/parent paths

Tags: python-2.7, filepath

I'm looking for a more Pythonic way to return a list of all parent paths, self-inclusive, from a given path.

For example, given:

```
"/dir1/dir2/dir3"
```

Return:

```
["/dir1", "/dir1/dir2", "/dir1/dir2/dir3"]
```

So far I'm essentially doing:

```
import os
path = os.path.normpath(path)
path_parts = path.split(os.sep)
```

Then iterating over the parts to reconstruct the list. I can't help but feel like it's an ugly kludge though...

Comment: There is no builtin function to do that. So, I would say, what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are already using a list comprehension to do it, so, if not, you could try something like the following:

```
import os

def get_branch_dirs(dir):
    levels = dir.split(os.path.sep)
    return [os.path.sep.join(levels[:i+1]+[""]) for i in range(len(levels))]

get_branch_dirs(dir="/dir1/dir2/dir3")
```

OUTPUT:

```
['/', '/dir1/', '/dir1/dir2/', '/dir1/dir2/dir3/']
```

You may want to tweak it if you expect the dir string to end in a "/"

---

---

**EDIT**: Actually, I just realised you didn't want the root directory listed, so try this instead:

```
def get_branch_dirs(dir):
    levels = dir.split(os.path.sep)
    return [os.path.sep.join(levels[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(levels))][1:]


get_branch_dirs(dir="/dir1/dir2/dir3")
```

OUTPUT

```
['/dir1', '/dir1/dir2', '/dir1/dir2/dir3']
```